# Is possible to check if a number is in an array with bit operators

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

Maybe it is nonsense. I've thought a lot about it and I would like to know if it's possible to somehow implement something like this: adding all the elements of the array and use the result against a bitmask to identify which are the numbers that are in the array. The truth is, I have no idea how to do this, but it would be more or less thereby.

Would this be possible or not?

Comment: I guess you want this to avoid looping through the array. In any solution you would need to loop through the array one way or another.

Comment: Sure, you can implement an equality check using bitwise operators (xnor, then horizontal AND), but why would you even do this?

Comment: @harold can you give an example, I am very interested this

Comment: 'Bloom filter' is probably relevant here.

Comment: Acually, this sounds like making a hash function/table that is smaller than the array of numbers to find whether the number is [probably] in the array. So you are looking for a hash function, and wonder if that can be using bit manipulation operators.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you add the numbers, you cannot identify if some special number is in the array. For example, imagine yo have the array

```
int a[2]={2,4};
```

The sum is 6, but 6 can come from 1+5, so you loss information with the sum. If your goal is to quickly find a number in an array, I suggest use binary_search. For reference, with example, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/
This is c++,not c, but you can find compatible implementations for c, like
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-binary-search

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if all elements of the array are exact powers of `2`.  In this case, the array can be replaced with the union of its elements and you can check if a number is in the array by checking if it is a power of `2` and if its only bit is present in the sum:

```
int sum = 0;
int array[] = { 1, 4, 8, 256, ... };
...
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array/sizeof *array; i++) {
    sum |= array[i];
}
...
int n = get_value_for_n();

if ((n & (n - 1)) == 0 && (sum & n) != 0) {
    // n is a power of 2 present in sum
}
```

If `n` is `0`, the test for power of `2` may give a false positive, but `sum & n` will be `0` anyway.

In most other cases, you would need to iterate over the array.  If this array is huge, you can sort it and use binary search to locate the number in it.

Comment: Purists may object that the above code should really use `unsigned int` to avoid undefined behaviour on `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Would this work if you don't know the size of the array and you have at least 2 equal elements in it?

Comment: @VAndrei: As long as the requirement that all array elements are exact powers of `2`, it works even if there are duplicates because I use `|` instead of `+`.  You need a way to iterate over the array... either you know the size, or you can compute it (that's what I do in the example) or you can tell the end from a particular value such as `0`.